# Parse.com search performance

Tags: performance, search, parse-platform

I have a Parse class, that I want to make searchable on a String attribute . According to Parse's [blog](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/) the most efficient way to do this is by using a list of lowercased words as your searchable String attribute. For example, instead of "My Search Term", use ["my", "search", "term"].

The problem is, that I want to be able to search substrings as well. So, an object with description "abc" should be returned for any of the following search strings: a, b, c, ab, bc or abc.

I thought about further breaking down the ["my", "search", "term"] tags into more words, so turn "my" into ["m", "y", "my"]. This list might become huge, though, in case of a slightly longer string (consider "search" for example).

Using [query.matches](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_matches) would solve this, but is not recommended for large datasets.

So, what is best way to approach this, considering, that most of the tags will be a lot longer than only 2 characters?

Answer (score 1):

You identified correctly the only two reasonable alternatives in parse.  And for nontrivial keywords, I think `query.matches` will be the only workable choice.

Consider relaxing the requirement that the user can search *any* substring of a string.  Isn't it unreasonable to suppose that I might search for the word "requirement" with the string "ire"?  If search is limited to matching prefixes, the query can use [`startsWith`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_startsWith).